# In .NET, How do I separate xml from compiled resource file?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, embedded-resource

We have a customer that would like to modify application user messages that we store in .resx files.  I'm thinking this can't be done since the xml file behind the .resx is embedded in a compiled dll.  Am I correct?  Or, is there a way keep the xml outside of the compiled dll?  I realize this can easily be done by other means but I like the ease of the resx file--the classes/properties are created for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Anything is possible of course, but it won't be nearly as convenient or easy to maintain.  It doesn't sound like a satellite assembly would fly here.  An application setting is about the easiest.  A good way to keep requests like these at bay is to quote an accurate price that includes the hassle of maintaining this for the next N years.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  It seems like our customer is trying to pinch every penny out of us by doing things like these themselves.  This may be one that we just say "no".